# Scores for train set split and ​test set split with cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have an exercise and I want to know if I'm doing it correctly.

Exercise:
Consider the data set and train a model Lasso, with cross validation kfold=10. Which MAE for the training set split, and then, which MAE for the test set split.

Also, in `cross_val_score`, the parameter 'scoring' in this case returns a negative value, I'm using np.absolute to get the positive value. This is right?

```
x= df.drop(columns='target', axis=1)
y= df.target

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(x, y, random_state=42)

cv = KFold(n_splits=10)

model = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.42)

scores_train= absolute(cross_val_score(model, x_train, y_train, cv=cv, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error'))
scores_train

scores_test= absolute(cross_val_score(model, x_test, y_test, cv=cv, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error'))
scores_test
```

Answer (score 0):

The convention for scoring function is `cross_val_score` is that higher return values are better than lower return values. Therefore metrics such as MAE are negated to follow this convention.

If you want to analyze the `mean_absolute_error` of your model it is therefore accepted to remove the negative sign using `np.absolute()` and treat results as MAE values.